# How to use pig with cassandra?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

I know that cassandra has hadoop integration, but it seems to be for a combination cassandra/hadoop cluster using cassandra's own imitation.

But is there a loader that can be used with pig in a separate hadoop cluster that can load/store to/from a separate cassandra cluster? It seems this does not actually exist but want to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you using PIG for ?

Moreover, I would suggest to have a look at Storm, it seems to be a viable alternative for your use case.